# VIM Background color issue

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want my vim background to be dark but as you can see it's not, its half black half grey, im using ubuntu 15.10 with latest vim version. How to fix this?
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otfun.png)

Comment: But which colorscheme are you using?

Comment: It seems he is using [jellybeans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your background was of all the same colour, which is set in your colorsheme, you need to comment the line about highlighting nonText.

```
" highlight Normal ctermbg=black
" highlight nonText ctermbg=black
```

If you wish to override the settings in your colorscheme, just uncomment the line about highlighting Normal

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=black
highlight nonText ctermbg=black
```

If you want to see the current settings of the highlighting, you can use `:highlight` command.

Read more in help

- [`:h highlight-groups`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups)

Comment: It's not fully black when i comment it, it's grey

Comment: You want it fully black?

Comment: Yes i want it fully black